# Interfacing WS2812B addressable LED to Wemos D1 mini

Tags: microcontroller, led, digital-logic, circuit-design, esp8266

I want to connect a single WS2812B LED to Wemos D1 mini ESP. Here is Maximum ratings and Electrical Characteristics.

[image]

[image]

Now the  voltage input High (VIH) of ESP is 3.3 V max which is less than (VIH)min=0.7 VDD which equals 3.5V.
1- Is this connection reliable for production without using a level converter?
2- Also What if I connect VDD to 3.3V of Wemos instead of 5V?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, let me see. (1) Let us first consider on Elect Char and forget Abs Max for now.  (2) And let us first consider Vdd = 5V and forget Vdd = 3V3 for now. (3) Now Vih min = 0.7Vdd = 0.7 * 5V = 3.5V, so should be OK (why?). (4) Now Vil max 0.3Vdd = 0.3 * 5V = 1.5V and also should be OK (why?). / to continue, ...

Comment: (5) Now I have done the first part of your home work for Vdd = 5V.  (6) Perhaps you can do the second part, Vdd = 3V3 and show us the results and (7) we will discuss it further, on abs max, hysteresis etc. :) Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @tlfong01 for your response, but VIHmin=3.5V and we have VIH=3.3V. Seems to me that the input may be floating now?

Comment: Ah yes, and @blaber has given a very good answer. So perhaps you can use (1)  Vdd = 5V, or (2) Use level converter to convert 3V3 logical signals to 5V0 logic signals. (3) And of course you also need to consider the (a) Safety margin, and (b) Hysteresis, etc. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: you don't need a level shifter. You can run a single pixel from the "5V" pin, which when powered from USB provides ~4.3v; it goes through a small surface-mount diode, so don't over-draw (~200ms) the "5V" pin, but a pixel or 3 is fine. `0.7*4.3vdd = 3v logic highs`. Beyond the math, i've done this for reals several times and it works.

Comment: @dandavis. You are 100 % correct, Just checked the schematics there is a B5819W before the +5V pin. The 3.3V input is reliable to use. Thank you very much

Comment: Stupid EE trick: carefully burn out the on-board diode with a 10ohm ceramic resistor from 5V to GND, so that it fails dead-short, then you can run a long strip of pixels from micros usb and wemos pin headers w/o over-heating. In the worst case, you can still drop a solder blob on the diode carcass.

Comment: @dandavis Why not just desolder said diode and bridge the pads with solder? Should be way faster than even finding a suitable resistor, and more reliable to boot.

Comment: @TooTea: because many folks who buy those dev boards don't have soldering irons or like doing SMT work on tiny parts, because it's fun to give up the smoke and still use it, and because it's faster to fry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is standard for CMOS that anything above 0.7VCC is considered a logical high and anything below 0.3VCC is a logical low. So if your WS2818B runs at 5V you will need a signal of at least 0.7 * 5 = 3.5v to be able to address it with a consistent logical high. Now in practice things might just work (even if your logical high is 3.3v) but I wouldn't call it "safe for production". The Wemos has a logical high of 3.3v regardless of how it is powered, so you will need to either step up the logical level of the Wemos through some external circuitry or (which is easier) diminish the supply voltage of the RGB strip to a VCC such that 0.7VCC < 3.3v. A simple compromise is to run both at 3.5v which is cutting close to the max rating of the Wemos and the min rating of the strip. Alternatively (as dandavis suggests) power both at 5v but put a diode in between the supply voltage and the WS2812B. This will drop the supply voltage of the WS2812B to 4.4v for a regular diode and now a logical level of 3.3v is enough since 0.7*4.4 = 3.08 < 3.3v.

Comment: The Wemos is powered with a 5V indeed, and the is also 3.3V pin available(Which I can power the LED from). There is no 3.6 V on the board, also using a level converter for just one LED is not a good idea? Can I get through with suppling the 3.3V to the VDD of the LED ?

Comment: You are right, I just read that the logic level for the Wemos is 3.3v even when it's powered at 5v. You can power both the RGB strip and the Wemos at 3.5v . For the Wemos it's close to the max rating and for the RGB it's close to the min rating. Alternatively power the Wemos at the usual 3.3V and the RGB strip at anything between 3.5v and 4.5v and the CMOS level will match.

Comment: Here for your reference: "Operate the NodeMCU on the 3.3V input with 2.5V to 3.6V" https://diyi0t.com/what-is-the-esp8266-pinout-for-different-boards/ . I edited my answer.

Comment: An alternative solution (as suggested by dandavis) is to power both with 5v but put a forward diode between the supply voltage and the WS2812B. This will drop the supply voltage of the WS2812B to 4.4v which is comfortably within specs and now 3.3v will certainly be a logic high for the WS2812B.

Comment: @blaber re: "an alternative solution" that's exactly what the usb input and "V5" (slight misnomer) pin do...

Comment: I edited my answer to give you credits.

Comment: whoo, +1. I discovered that diode on accident by burning the @#%$ out of my finger running a strip of 10 pixels...

Comment: Interesting to note: I have 12v pixels as well, xmas lights, and those respect the wemos' 3.3v logic as well, and i've never had issue with running a real 5v to the pixels and ESP to the data. Don't use a resistor. do use a moderate capacitor on each end of the strip.

Comment: While I never tried this, I'm not entirely surprised since the CMOS gates in the WS2812B must be similar to the gate of a MOSFET. For low voltages at the gate the drain source acts like a resistor, so in particular it must still register a "high". As you know the down-side is that we don't have any real guarantees as to what happens in the 0.3Vcc - 0.7Vcc range, which is not good for production but cool for running your strip at home :)

Answer (score 2):

The VIH of Wemos is irrelevant because it is not used as an input. You must look at VOH of Wemos which is the output high voltage. For a CMOS output at 3.3V operation driving a small load like input of a next chip can be assumed to be 3.3V.

And the LED nominal operating range is 4.5V to 5.5V, so 3.3V logic levels are not necessarily enough and it might not work reliably. Also powering the LED below minimum voltage of 4.5V might not work.

So if the Wemos pin is not 5V tolerant, you need a level shifter of some sort. Preferably a HCT type buffer chip like a 74HCT125 or anything that has an input and output that does not invert, or if inverts, use two inverting gates like a 74HCT04.

Comment: The WS2812B electrical rating is in the 3.5V to 5.3V range so powering it at 4.4V should work just fine.

Comment: Stupid EE trick #2: Each pixel level shifts data to 5V on the way to data out, so if you have a near-threshold issue, use a "sacrificial pixel", or tape up the first LED, then the rest of them will work perfectly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSGfkL1AGKs ... Might be faster/cheaper than waiting on an extra part...

Comment: @blaber I don't think it works at 3.5V. The nominal operating range is clearly said to be from 4.5V to 5.5V. For some reason, the absolute maximum characteristics contain a range from 3.5V to 5.3V, and that means the part gets damage when operated beyond these values, but it does not mean it will work properly when used beyond nominal operating range of 4.5V to 5.5V. On a side note, it also makes no sense to have a range of +3.5V to +5.3V, because 5.5V is allowed, and 0V must be allowed to have unpowered LED. It is just a bad quality datasheet.